# Use costom fieldnames within the resultsPanel from OrgChart.js (balkangraph)

Tags: javascript, orgchart

How can I use my own name in the ResultsPanel instead of the one from the nodes []?

It would be the best if this could be switched dynamically.

[image]

This could also be interesting for multilingualism.

```
chart.editUI.on('field', function(sender, args){
  switch (args.systemType) {
    case 'A':
      return var name= 'Ordername',
      break;
    case 'B':
      return var name= 'Reordername';
      break;
    default:
  }
});
```

```js
        var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
            template: "mila",
            enableSearch: false,
            mouseScrool: OrgChart.action.none,
            nodeBinding: {
                field_0: "name",
                field_1: "title"
            },
            nodes: [
                { id: 1, name: "Car", title: "Product" },
                { id: 2, pid: 1, systemType: "A", name: "BMW", title: "Order" },
                { id: 3, pid: 1, systemType: "B", name: "RENAULT", title: "Invoice" }
            ]
        });
```

```css
html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Helvetica;
        }

        #tree {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://balkangraph.com/js/latest/OrgChart.js"></script>
<div id="tree"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's to late you can try this, it works for me.
you should apply your switch on the 'args.name' and then select the fields (fields contains the details 'html for that field' and than you set your custom label)

```
switch(args.name)
        {
            case 'name' :
                var lbl = args.field.querySelector('div');
                lbl.innerHTML = "Your custom label :";
                var txt = args.field.querySelector('input');
                break;
            case 'title' :
                var lbl = args.field.querySelector('div');
                lbl.innerHTML = "Your custom label :";
                var txt = args.field.querySelector('input');
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Hey, please add some context instead of just code snippet. A few words around what is code doing and why, should be helpful.